# Are scopes within each independent directive isolated and private within that directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

The html code is as follows

```
<div class="dir-view" >
    // unable to get {{ button.content }}
    <button type="button" id="notworking" ng-show="button.content.length" >{{ button.content }}</button>

</div>
<div class="dir-design" >
     //able to get {{ button.content }}
    <button type="button" id="working" ng-show="button.content.length" >{{ button.content }}</button>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="label label-primary" for="button-content">BUTTON CONTENT :</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <textarea class="form-control" id="button-content" rows="4" cols="50" ng-model="button.content"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the above code dir-view and dir-design are the custom directives I have defined .

In the button tag within div#dir-view I am unable to get {{ button.content }} .

whereas within div#dir-design I am able to get {{ button.content }}.

I think that the scope object within the dir-design directive is not accessible within the dir-view .

Is this the reason why I am unable to access **{{ button.content }}** inside dir-view.

Are the scopes within each directive isolated and private to that directive ?.

If I am right , can someone please guide me in solving this problem by making **{{ button.content }}**  of one directive dir-design, accessible even within dir-view (that is the neighboring directive ).

Also if possible please guide me to good document on angular js scopes.

attaching the scope screen I got from angular debug chrome plugin 
[image]

My controller.js file content showing directive

```
angular.module('modFoundation', ['$strap.directives'])
     //directive to include view panel
    .directive('dirView', function() {
       return {
           restrict : 'CAME',
           templateUrl: 'templates/view.html',
           transclude: true
       };
    })
    //directive to include design panel
    .directive('dirDesign', function() {
        return {
            restrict : 'CAME',
            templateUrl: 'templates/design.html',
            transclude: true
        };
    })
```

Comment: Your question contains a lot but it isn't entirely clear what your goal is IMO.  If you could post a plunkr or jsfiddle as well to show the issue in action it would help... From what your describing it sounds like you want to use require in the directive definition object to have access to the controller of one directive from another or else perhaps you would benefit from using a service or value to share some data between directives.

Comment: k  i will come up with a plunkr

Comment: Yes will watch that tutorial ..

Comment: Here's a site that has lots of good tutorials in fairly short segments: http://egghead.io/search?q=directive

Comment: yes looking into it . and will find the solution soon . Thanks for the help .

Comment: No problem if you come up with the solution yourself you can post your own answer too and accept it if you're able to get it worked out.

Comment: finally I came up with  a simple solution , minimal code , no misuse of angular . directives still remain reusable , directives can even be used independently . Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how i made two directives communicate ?

Concept :
The two directives were siblings .There is a new scope created for each directive which is clearly visible in the diagram .
So to make these two communicate one would be to introduce a service and inject into each directive , but that takes away the re usability of the directives and brings in strong dependency between them . so we should find a way to do this without affecting re-usability.

As these are siblings, the idea would be to make communication possible via parent , so just introduce an controller which simply does

$scope.button = {}

Done .

To understand the idea of communication between two children the following code will be helpful .

```
> $scope
Scope {$id: "002", $$childTail: Child, $$childHead: Child, $$prevSibling: null, $$nextSibling: null…}

> child1 = $scope.$new()
Child {$id: "005", this: Child, $$listeners: Object, $parent: Scope, $$asyncQueue: Array[0]…}

> child2 = $scope.$new()
Child {$id: "006", this: Child, $$listeners: Object, $parent: Scope, $$asyncQueue: Array[0]…}

> child1.$parent
Scope {$id: "002", $$childTail: Child, $$childHead: Child, $$prevSibling: null, $$nextSibling: null…}

> child2.$parent
Scope {$id: "002", $$childTail: Child, $$childHead: Child, $$prevSibling: null, $$nextSibling: null…}

> $scope.button = {}
Object {}

> child1.button
Object {}

> child2.button
Object {}

> child1.button.c1v1 = "hello"
"hello"

> child2.button.c1v1
"hello"

> child2.button.c2v2 = "world"
"world"

> child2.button.c2v2
"world"

> $scope.button.c1v1
"hello"

> $scope.button.c2v2
"world"





           $scope 
              |
     _________|___________
    |                     |
    |                     |
   child1               child2
```

The use case is explained in the jsfiddle

not working case : http://plnkr.co/edit/OoAuHzP8YW8NXk8I5qtc?p=preview

working case : http://plnkr.co/edit/bx4vBavcfwQYyeJqEkfU?p=preview